# Display text when hover on image

Tags: jquery, html, image, text, hover

I want to both change to another image and display text when hover on an image. I've succeeded changing to another image on hover but I don't know how to display the text. And I also want to customize the text (color, size, position). My code:

```html
<section id="works">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="desktop-12 columns"><div class="border-top"></div></div>

   
    <a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item first-row">
       <h3>Bird</h3>
       <span class="category">Illustration</span>

       <img src="images/thumb_item01.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/thumb_item01a.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/thumb_item01.png';"/>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     </div><!-- // .desktop-3 -->
                  <div class="clear"></div>
    </a>
    </div></section>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your full HTML ?

Comment: I've edited the post with the full code, plz check, thank you

Comment: What kind of text do you want to display? There is a title attribute you can use for pictures to simply display it's title.
You can also use the css :hover pseudo class  in order to show content when someone hovers over a parent element.

Comment: @Phuong Also, don't forget to accept the answer of your choice, by clicking the gray check mark below to the answer's score

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `:hover` to show the text, here used with the sibling selector `+`

And by using a class for your CSS rule, like this `.showtext:hover + div`, you only need one for all your texts, in opposite of an `id`, which needs to be unique for each text

*Updated based on comment*

*To have the text on top of the image I added a wrapper around them and gave the text a position*

```css
.imgwrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.showtext + div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 250px;
}
.showtext:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="works">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="desktop-12 columns">
      <div class="border-top"></div>
    </div>

    <a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
      <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
        <div class="item first-row">
          <h3>Bird</h3>
          <span class="category">Illustration</span>

          <div class="imgwrapper">
            <img class="showtext" src="http://placehold.it/250" onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/250/0ff';" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/250';" />

            <div>Some text to be shown on top of the image</div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- // .item -->
      </div>
      <!-- // .desktop-3 -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, Im a beginner. Do I have to name the div? because I have many other divs, and if so should it be img + #name and img:hover + #name?

Comment: @Phuong Updated my answer, and by using a class, like this `.showtext:hover + div`, you only need one for all your images

Comment: Thank you, it displays the text but the text is beneath the image, I want the text to be on the image, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Phuong Updated my answer again, showing how to do that

Comment: it works perfectly!! much appreciation! Can I ask what's the purpose of .imgwraper?

Comment: @Phuong As the text is positioned it needs to know from where to start, and as the image depends on the text before it, the wrapper groups the image and text, make it easy to position it without using a script to detect the image start position

Answer (score 1):

Use `mousenter` and `mouseleave` in a single query.

I would recommend to apply particular selector class `.firstImage` to your image.

```js
$('.firstImage').on({
  mouseenter: function (evt) {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x350')
    $(this).parent('div').css('color', 'red');
  },
  mouseleave: function (evt) {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x150')  
    $(this).parent('div').css('color', 'blue');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="works">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="desktop-12 columns"><div class="border-top"></div></div>

   
    <a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item first-row">
       <h3>Bird</h3>
       <span class="category">Illustration</span>

       <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="firstImage"/>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     </div><!-- // .desktop-3 -->
                  <div class="clear"></div>
    </a>
    </div></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".myimg").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).attr({src:"http://kurld.com/images/wallpapers/flower-image/flower-image-18.jpg"});
        $(".txt").show();
        
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).attr({src:"https://static.pexels.com/photos/67857/daisy-flower-spring-marguerite-67857.jpeg"});
        $(".txt").hide();
        
    })
})
```

```css
 img {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   }
.txt {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  }
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  }
```

```html
 <section id="works">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="desktop-12 columns"><div class="border-top"></div></div>
    <a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
     <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
      <div class="item first-row">
       <h3>Bird</h3>
       <span class="category">Illustration</span>
                            <div class="wrapper">
       <img class="myimg" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/67857/daisy-flower-spring-marguerite-67857.jpeg" />
                            <div class="txt">Red Flower</div>
                            </div>
      </div><!-- // .item -->
     </div><!-- // .desktop-3 -->
                  <div class="clear"></div>
    </a>
    </div></section>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is just give an id to that Text "div" and update it to your CSS:

```css
img + div {
  display: none;
}
img:hover + #ImageText {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id="works">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="desktop-12 columns">
      <div class="border-top"></div>
    </div>


    <a href="single-illustration-sidebar-left.html" class="permalink">
      <div class="desktop-3 mobile-half columns">
        <div class="item first-row">
          <h3>Bird</h3>
          <span class="category">Illustration</span>

          <img src="http://placehold.it/50" onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/50/f00';" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/50';" />

          <div id="ImageText">Some text to be shown</div>
        </div>
        <!-- // .item -->
      </div>
      <!-- // .desktop-3 -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, it displays the text but the text is beneath the image, I want the text to be on the image, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @Phuong you can Just add a span containing image text which is hidden. on image Hover you will have to just show that text span.